# How to let users login in and send emails through their account?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, google-cloud-firestore, email-client

I'm trying to build an application that users can log in to and send emails. I'm using FIrebase with ReactJS. For sending out emails, I am currently using email.js. It's been working well, however, I can only send out emails through my own email.js account. So if I create an account with my gmail, it will send emails out through my own email. However, I want the user to login to my app (I'm using firebase auth), and when they send out emails, I want it to come from the email address they logged into my app with. I haven't found out how to do this with email.js documentation and there isn't anything that clear online. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried using the Extension called [Trigger Email](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/firestore-send-email)?

Comment: Although @Alex Mamo option is the best but if you want more customization then you can also use [React email](https://react.email/)

Comment: @AlexMamo I looked up trigger email but all the tutorials show it sending email from your own account (firebase admin). I want to build something similar to mailchimp where a user logs in and can send an email from their account. Like if you use my app, and you send an email, it will be sent from your email account, not mine even though I'm the developer. Is it possible to do this with Trigger Email?